# Would I accelerate in the same direction as my friend inside the event horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, tidal-effect

Imagine my friend and I fell into the event horizon of the Gargantua, the blackhole from the movie interstellar with the mass of 100 million times of our Sun. Would I be able to tell that both of us are accelerating towards the singularity or we will be floating endlessly while maintaining eye contact? The suits should keep us safe against the radiation and we shouldn't have turned into spaghetti the instant we enter the event horizon right?

Comment: If you follow your friend with a 1-second delay, upon crossing the horizon you would be separated in space roughly by 1-light-second (like the distance from the Earth to the Moon). Also, on the inside (assuming no rotation for simplicity), the singularity  is not a location in space, but a future moment in time that happens everywhere in space. Finally, acceleration depends on the choice of coordinates. For example, in the remote coordinates, an object falling from momentary rest at the horizon does not move inside at all. So you need to provide more details on what exactly you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This video from ScienceClic is good. [What would we see if we fell into a Black Hole?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rTv9wvvat8). But you might watch a few others first.

Here is a quick and easy explanation of why you can't get out of a black hole. [Black holes are Bubbles of light](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuWvJXZT5vQ)

Here is an explanation of gravity as curvature of spacetime. This is used extensively in the What would we see video. [A new way to visualize General Relativity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwgIjBUYVc).

Here is Veritasium explaining what a black hole looks like from a distance. It goes over some of the same things as What would you see, but is clearer. [How to Understand What Black Holes Look Like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUyH3XhpLTo)

Comment: In the movie Gargantua is a nearly extremely rotating bh. Near horizon structure and thus experiences of infalling observers are considerably different from those for non-rotating bhs.